# Middle align viewport with scroll effect on section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that open and closes various sections dependant on the box selected.

I need these sections to be in the middle of the viewport once clicked (with a smooth animation if possible)

Here's my current script:

```
$(function() {
  $('.box').each(function() {
    var targetElement = $($(this).data('target'));
    targetElement.slideUp()
    $(this).click(function() {
      if(targetElement.is(':visible')) {
        targetElement.slideUp();
        adjustHeight();
        $("element").paroller();
      } else {
        targetElement.slideDown()
        targetElement.siblings('.section').slideUp()
        adjustHeight();
        $("element").paroller();
      }
    })
  })
});
```

I need 'targetElement' to be centered in the viewport after it opens.

Answer (score 0):

I use a function that i found to animate the scrolling,
pass it the element you wish to scroll and the scroll offset to scroll to.

```
function scrollTo (element, to, duration) {
    var start = element.scrollTop,
        change = to - start,
        currentTime = 0,
        increment = 20;

    var animateScroll = function () {
        currentTime += increment;
        element.scrollTop = Math.easeInOutQuad(currentTime, start, change, duration);
        if (currentTime < duration) {
            setTimeout(animateScroll, increment);
        }
    };
    animateScroll();
};

var targetElement = $($(this).data('target')).offset().top;
scrollTo(document.body, targetElement, 1000);
```

Comment: Is there no way to have this within the function I have already and make it pull through the targetElement variable?

Comment: take the scrollTo function and put it outside jquery scope, and these two lines put inside your code where you want to call the action:
`var targetElement = $($(this).data('target')).offset().top;
scrollTo(document.body, targetElement, 1000);`